# Compare strings in random order

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare 2 strings with same no of characters but in any order using javascript. For example I would like to compare the following
`str1 = "a, b, c, d"` with `str2 = "b, a, c, d"` and it should return true as long as both of them have same no of characters in any order.

Thanks

Comment: Sort the string characters first, then compare.

Comment: *same no of characters in any order...* so just compare the lengths?! `str1.length === str2.length`

Comment: ok...but str1 = "a, b, c, d" should not be equals str2 = "r, c, m, q"

Comment: Then you might want to rephrase your question?

Comment: Please clarify the task at hand. It might be good for yourself to try to formally and most clearly define your goal. In your case, it would seem you mean "do these two strings represent a comma delimited list of the same values, disregarding order". If that's *not* what you meant, please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

```
var compare = function(str1, str2) {
  return str1.replace(/\s/g, "").split(",").sort().join() === str2.replace(/\s/g, "").split(",").sort().join()
}
```

Comment: how to close the question?

Comment: @user3368953 Accept this answer after the timelimit.

Comment: sorry:) but how to do that? and can i rate u for the answer and Zvona

Comment: More concise: `'' + str1.replace(/[\s,]/g,'').split('').sort()`, but the OP does not say "remove whitespace and commas".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "these two strings are comma delimited list of single characters, do they have the same the characters", then the shortest solution is

```
str1.split("").sort() === str2.split("").sort()
```

We split the string to characters, sort them so they are the same order. We do need to need to remove whitespace or compare commas since the poster said the strings have the same number of characters.

Comment: Confused about the down vote, looks fine to me. *trim* seems unnecessary.

Comment: Trim was there to help with whitespace, but given the poster said it's the same number of characters, it is indeed unneeded. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Convert string to array `JSON.parse("[" + string + "]");` and then compare those two arrays by iterating through them and checking elements.

You can also use `split` method on String object to convert it into an array.

Comment: There are much cleaner ways. See other answers.